# How can we see logs just after and before particular text in Google Cloud Logging?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

In Google Cloud Logging, using `advanced search` Can we search for a `text` and then see logs present after and before that particular text?

Like for example in a PDF, doc or any file when you search for a word then after searching that word you can see content just above and below of the searched text, but in google cloud logging we can only see texts where words are present, but not the content present just above and below it.

Can anyone please tell me is it possible to search just above and below logs present in Google Cloud Logging or not?

Answer (score 12):

You can do this by pinning the log entry: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview#pin

Once the entry is pinned, you can relax the filter to match whatever other entries would be helpful for context.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built in feature in Google Cloud Logging like the one you are describing.

However, what you can do with advanced filters is [searching by time](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters#search-by-time). This way you can search for a `text` and then, based on the `timestamp`of that log, search with timeframe filter.

For example, the `text` log has a timestamp of `2016-11-29T23:00:00Z`. Now you can search for it's context with a filter that has an upper and lower time limit from that timestamp, like this one:

```
timestamp >= "2016-11-29T22:55:00Z"
timestamp <= "2016-11-29T23:05:00Z"
```

---

If this workaround is not enough, then feel free to [create a new feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) in Google's [Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/) explaining in more detail the kind of feature you would want to see introduced in Google Cloud Logging.

Comment: So first I have to search for the text and then again search with timestamp :(, there must have been any easy workaround, not something expected from google team :(, thanks anyways.